# sort array of type int with the help of comparator

Tags: java

I am using sort fun of arrays and it is showing me error like this is not valid . Help me

```
import java.util.*;

class power
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        Arrays.sort(a,new Comparator<int []>()
        {
            public int compare(int a1[],int a2[])
            {
                String s1=""+a1[0];
                String s2=""+a2[0];
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: error is there on sort fun. Not a valid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write a `Comparator<int>` because Java primitive types can't be used as generics. You'll need the `Integer` wrapper type. So change

```
int a[] = new int[n];
```

to

```
Integer a[] = new Integer[n];
```

And then your comparator should be comparing two `Integer`(s) (not two `int[]`(s)). Like

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer a1, Integer a2) {
        String s1 = "" + a1;
        String s2 = "" + a2;
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
```

or just

```
Arrays.sort(a, (x, y) -> String.valueOf(x).compareTo(String.valueOf(y)));
```